# How to sort a list with a given order?

Tags: list, perl, sorting

I'm trying to do the following. I have a predefined list to be used as a "order by" on an given list.

```
my @orderby = ( 'car', 'boat', 'chicken', 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse');
   or
my %orderby = ( 'car' => 0, 'boat' => 1, 'chicken' => 2, 'cat' => 3, 'dog' => 4, 'mouse' => 5);

my @list = ('boat', 'car', 'mouse', 'chicken');
```

I tried infinite ways to sort it and I didn't get what I want. I have searched on google, and here, but I did not found the answer.

`@list` need to be sorted in that way:

```
sort @list using %orderby
```

The print that I want after the sort:

```
car, boat, chicken, mouse
```

BTW, @list can have duplicated entries:

```
my @list = ('boat', 'car', 'mouse', 'chicken', 'mouse', 'car');
```

In that case, the print need to be:

```
car, car, boat, chicken, mouse, mouse
```

Do you guys have a solution for that?
or maybe another approach.
Thanks!!

Comment: Re your update, my solutions handle duplicates.

Comment: yes, I have tested that! Thx again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
my @orderby = qw( car boat chicken cat dog mouse );
my @list    = qw( boat car mouse chicken );

my %orderby = map { $orderby[$_] => $_ } 0..$#orderby;

my @sorted = sort { $orderby{$a} <=> $orderby{$b} } @list;
```

---

Or if you want to mess with people's minds,

```
my @orderby = qw( car boat chicken cat dog mouse );
my @list    = qw( boat car mouse chicken );

my %counts; ++$counts{$_} for @list;
my @sorted = map { ($_) x ($counts{$_}||0) } @orderby;
```

Comment: The array to be sorted is `list`, not `orderby`.

Comment: oh my, that was fast. Now I will try to understand map.  thank you!

Comment: For each element of the list passed to `map`, apply a function to it (the code in the curlies). The resulting lists are joined into one big list and returned. In the first snippet, I use `map` to generate the `%orderby` you had in your question without hardcoding all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Surely if you have a list of all the potential items in order, and a smaller list of the items you want to select, then this is actually a selection problem, and not a sorting problem?

```
my %items = map { $_ => 1 } @list;
my @items = grep { $items{$_} } @orderby;
```

Runs in O(n) time rather than O(n log n) too :)

Comment: That's basically the same as the second of the solutions I posted 4 days earlier, except mine's better because it handles duplicates, and yours doesn't meet the OP's specs because it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Radix sort is a good choice for that case:

```
use Sort::Key::Radix qw(ukeysort);
@sorted = ukeysort { $orderby{$_} } @data;
```